# Export json data into single cell

Tags: mysql, json, copy

My problem is a relatively simple one; unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any solutions from searching around.

I have a SQL table called alerts from which I'm trying to export data into CSV files. Everything works fine except when including the final column `custom_info`. This column contains a lot of important diagnostic information, but it's in JSON format, which means there are commas **everywhere**. As such, my CSV file ends up having a new column for every single field separated by a comma.

Is there a way to force this data to remain in one cell (i.e., retain it's proper JSON format)? I've tried playing around with different options for `FIELDS TERMINATED BY`, but to no avail.

Many thanks!

Comment: Specify `ENCLOSED`.